# It is necessary to include a random number in the step you want or not include it

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, specflow

include a random number in the specific steps you want
Example:

```
Feature: Zonas

@TEST
Scenario Outline: TEST
Given Insert <Descripcion>
And insert <CodigoDeInterfaz>
And Validate Description <Descripcion>
And Validate CodigoDeInterfaz <CodigoDeInterfaz>
Examples:
| Descripcion    | CodigoDeInterfaz      |
| DescTH6456565          | CodDeIntHT45645645
```

i need include random number in values

```
Examples:
| Descripcion    | CodigoDeInterfaz      |
| Desc <RANDOM>  | CodDeIntHT <RANDOM>   | <---- here
```

so the input parameters all include the random number

1. SpecFlow 2.3.2
2. C#
3. NUnit 3

Comment: Is that an exclusive "or"?

Comment: Using random numbers in test makes the test indeterministic. Test should always be deterministic. You are doing it wrong.

Comment: I need to run the same test several times and the fields are unique, I need to implement random numbers, it is a requirement

Comment: @EdPlunkett: No. it's the syntax of SpecFlow. Simple "grid" layout.

Comment: @EdPlunkett:Well... It's rather Gherkin... :)

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen Random does not indeterrministic. if you use the same seed for your random data it will be random but still deterministic

Answer (score 2):

You can **try** to use [Specflow.DSL](https://github.com/wenyuansong/Specflow.DSL).

```
Feature: Zonas

@TEST
Scenario Outline: TEST
Given Insert <Descripcion>
And insert <CodigoDeInterfaz>
And Validate Description <ValidateDescripcion>
And Validate CodigoDeInterfaz <ValidateCodigoDeInterfaz>
Examples:
| Name   | Descripcion                     | ValidateDescripcion  | CodigoDeInterfaz                     | ValidateCodigoDeInterfaz |
| Random | [[Descripcion=RegEx([0-9]{7})]] | [[Descripcion]]      | [[CodigoDeInterfaz=RegEx([0-9]{7})]] | [[CodigoDeInterfaz]]     |
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this IMHO is to use a `StepArgumentTransformation`, something like this:

```
[Then("And Validate Description (.*)")]
public void ThenValidateDescription(RandomisedValue description)
{}

[StepArgumentTransformation]
public RandomisedValue ToRandomisedValue(string initialInput)
{
    return initialInput + GetRandomData();
}
```

specflow will call your step argument transformation method with the data in the method, you add your random element and return the class that represents the data that has been randomised. As long as you have a distinct class for each type of randomisation you want then specflow will be able to determine which of the step argument transformations it should call...